# Firebird command get data from month

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

How can i get values from selected month without specific date like mysql command below

```
select doc_code 
from docheader 
where month(doc_date) = 6
```

What is the sql command in firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebird supports the standard [`extract`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-extract.html) function:

```
select doc_code 
from docheader 
where extract(month from doc_date) = 6
```

Comment: As it doesn't seem to deserve another question, for month 6 to 8 it would be `where extract(month from doc_date) between 6 and 8`